# onclick radio button fadeout body and redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="language-container">
    <form id="language_radio">  
        <input type="radio" value="//domain.tld/page.php?lang=02" name="language" id="alb">
        <label for="alb">Shqip</label>
        <input type="radio" value="//domain.tld/page.php?lang=03" name="language" id="eng">
        <label for="eng">English</label>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#language_radio input[type=radio]").change(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = $(this).val();
        $("body").fadeOut(800, newpage);
});
</script>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is, when a radio button is selected, I want to fade out the entire body, and then redirect to another page.

However, I can't seem to get it to do anything. It won't fade out or redirect.

How can do I fix it (newb to JS) :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("html").fadeOut();
```

as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#language_radio input[type=radio]").change(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // This variable is useless
    // You can remove it if it's not
    // being used
    newLocation = $(this).val();
    $("html").fadeOut(800, function() {
        // Redirect to the newLocation here
        // similar behavior as clicking on a link
        window.location.href = newLocation;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Like this `$("html").fadeOut(800, function() { location.href = $(this).val();});` ? And why `html` not `body`?

Comment: theorictly only body is visible part of html page :D

Comment: Boris, @NullPoiиteя you're both right, there is no 'functional' impact, but since html supersedes body in hierarchy this will guarantee that all the page will fade out and no element is left out.

Comment: @BassemDy Cool, it fades out. But it doesn't take the value from the radio, which is the url that it needs to redirect to... It only reloads the page

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. *BTW, tried it with `$(document)`, it didn't work that way...

Comment: @Boris, hmm it `$(document).hide() and $(document).fadeOut()` are throwing a TypeError, will investigate and see what changed..

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by

```
$("#language_radio input[type=radio]").change(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    $("body").fadeOut(1000,function(){
       window.location.href = $(this).val();
    })
 });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swamimmayank/fjqwhsrr/)

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#language_radio input[type=radio]").change(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    newLocation = $(this).val();
    $("html").fadeOut(800, function() {
        window.location.href = newLocation;
    });
});
</script>
```